# How do I extract value if the response contains dynamic value in jmeter?

Tags: dynamic, jmeter, token, beanshell

**The response is:**

```html
)]}'

[[["gf.alr",1,"AEThLlxiVQDDDuuI73Jmd31c5jpEIKuHo0vrp8McvenkLiqigngoeKFqm0_-z5wZ2BfLlw9qDMImaqxq5id_gvF4YxbWwX1cyGELwLQ88cji6bmL-UN3ofmzJuunMj_enuVQkmsHnbDr4-m5BA3AETovxRnIl-WPkj3Bxx9HswfvzTlcl2ny88m8T9uCGZWoI5w9tVovElHcm8lIF3bb6UW8S-1kzdncSD_kzUeXZudKgbXv6E01eXp8TRjrNR_RyPNR-4m8LknTHxXU--YT9vVRh42dGDbFNOkMANdAhdy_PDcDugguFSDfWfsEM5JSipkwMyJvl7GeECi6NHJ7jUCCwHpkDnmNZpDmiiOpHM_0_hlilEX91hyv2gcfVzn77ck6odWZu5pLYKtYM-0ZsKbNY3ei6cyr1vP2p7vo9eSbDF0xAa8Pn2VPQYoWmio_6iP6SrhTa9g0QYXIxA8df_hxv1sqdr4PSQXyHf_93A2Wg6sJOdwOeg_eYXsjRufRa3GOHqhAzJ3yjBSYWj5whaEki3dkPpblaiJm5u9iUUxffnhnI8_777joy3tdLkZ3HNNc4rYbewOzb8YaemBdY0AKTwwB5QEv7HfdgrJ1Li_rqP92hnVIpm_vQFVE_8qe3X7iROI6eneDXVpKYSYM1ghZAWzC4zxLXYaE1XxYG5HsJ9CH1Y2z-LTxDe7nL1vzyhqIuwSEozuzVeqaupJT2cjH8VGGJMea_8wvfRwe66YuzYpzn0hzlWI",[["mycredentials@domain.com",null,null,null,null,"mycredentials@domain.com","domain.com",null,null,2]
]
,null,null,null,["gf.sisr",1,null,null,[[[null,null,"FIRST_AUTH_FACTOR",1,null,"INITIALIZED",null,null,1,7,1,1,null,null,null,null,"abhijeetv@siliconasiaworks.com","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAKWJJPMh4CWOEpGsDVKrzVyDPK4g8kVpQ/photo.jpg",null,null,1,null,[]
,{"1001":[1]
,"5001":[]
}]
]
,0,1,1,1,1,1,null,[null,[3]
,null,null,3]
,[null,null,null,null,0]
]
]
]
,["gf.ttu",0,"AMV8YcSeVlHXMrzQ3Ba_Oip51a7MQnrSgdnu_0EgtfHHffQOWgmV4aJT6c6KS3tx"]
,["e",3,null,null,1419]
]]
```

**In next request, I have to pass a value like to a parameter(tvalue):**

```html
["AEThLlyugKwRMH-FsGf8cKwGBg576SkJ3bC9caE39V5QllmRcVp-Gwoyy-EqqY7XN2ftg6FKx6KDJBiPciSSgzIFRLGHGAu0IOsi_xdX8BTOEFDeSCCYyxjU2jlaEjh-WASm6BWM3it9wGXqYHTFl6l-DURBA5Kt08BbdpvyW-XJGvbvlBUIeWtr3TeCuL7NRFaVFqO0bYDiIEo6eDkd6oAN6TLudS8b0yN6LeKLu6bkFeYZFF5G2jC05B0ry_1ytj7d_etfvaOXEgbnh8-3piD95jWd3xV8r7bI5odOlewzJ-J8yoixDkroXhfR2va2OVp-iY6z0wyQowPEJJEsdwrWdJBMkE0AAYMqa8hWD-joyqSsATdLGCYRxZDDW9cFt1EnvqizKDPiuGL-kkUqFf-B7MZuhvd8jsEjmeocHCrfxOLlut6SXghT7MmkcLnwT3IokaMPySSLQP97OiA517g51SsqJI38CaS-2LvgHiKP4vDrTtyz7vovVbJddcvyLhgBx4bdbdbQXpCrFVR6OPAIVbEqKrxgq69gYnqmR6EOzOUdVfluSDveeX4mNksvXKzu-ruzwta71rbKjSYKBHQ5qnGJmwziEoc_9farV2sQj8P6zZiAuiBXBaFbK3LfsvvT-kQ2ZcgqKvK8co3eVAhK9HI0_H0_TxizR7cSjKMwomxcHclWe69s-W47B7tppcQdNx1eGjuryYsKbCiIB7MDi90e6ZPcVWeNyx7KHfniSQDhcRtz0m0Fvp5d1LjYzG5fKh-fJh_U",null,1,null,[1,null,null,null,["thisispassword",null,true]]]
```

How may I extract the value and pass it to the parameter **tvalue**? Please help.

FYI:
The web portal used gmail credentials for login to the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the value you're looking for into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) called `tvalue` using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) configured like:

[image]

Just in case the [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query:

```
$.[0].[0].[2]
```

Once done you can amend the next request like:

```
["${tvalue}",null,1,null,[1,null,null,null,["thisispassword",null,true]]]
```